# The only irrep of a group of order p over a field of characteristic p is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I found an answer to my bigger question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572564/any-irreducible-representation-of-a-p-group-over-a-field-of-characteristic-p), but I'm curious about my attempted proof in the case where $|G|=p$.  I'm nearly certain this does not work, but I can still learn something from it.  Do I have the right idea at all?

Let $p$ be a prime, $P=\langle c \rangle$ a group of order $p$, and $F$ a field of characteristic $p$.  I want to show that the only irreducible representation of $P$ over $F$ is the trivial representation.  I am told to do this "using the fact that $F$ contains all $p$th roots of $1$ (namely $1$ itself)."

I am not sure about how to use the $p$th roots (just $1 \in F$), but here's what I did:

Let $A$ be a left $FP$-module, where $FP$ is the group ring of $P$ over $F$.  Also, let $P$ be a left $F$-module.  Take an element $0 \ne g \in A$ and consider the elements $g, (1c)g, (1c^2)g, ..., (1c^{p-1})g$.  Then these elements form a nontrivial proper(?) submodule of $A$ since for an arbitrary $a_1c^{j_1}+\cdots + a_pc^{j_p} \in FP$, we have $(a_1c^{j_1}+\cdots + a_pc^{j_p})(1c^ig)=\cdots=(a_1c^{i+j_1} + \cdots + a_pc^{i+j_p})g = c^kg$ for some $c^k \in P$, since $P$ is an $F$-module.  It follows that $A$ is reducible, and we have proved the contrapositive.

Thanks.

Comment: No reason for that submodule to be proper. For instance, if $A$ is cyclic, generated by $g$.

Comment: Hint: look at (1-c)^{p}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your argument is that a cyclic submodule need not be a proper one.

Any module contains a cyclic submodule (pick an element and form the submodule it generates), and any cyclic $R$-module is isomorphic to a quotient $R/I$. Use $F[C_p]\cong F[X]/(X^p-1)$ and the factorization of $X^p-1$ in characteristic $p$ to determine all ideals and hence all quotients of $F[C_p]$ and determine which one has no proper submodule (equivalently, which quotient is a field).