# Sylow $p$-Subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I know that one of the Sylow $p$-subgrouops of $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)(q=p^a)$ is the subgroup $P$ of upper triangular matrices with $1$ on diagonal, but is there a simple and direct way to see that every Sylow $p$-subgroup is obtained by change of basis isomorphism $T^{-1}PT=\{T^{-1}UT: U\in P\}, T\in GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ from this one(i.e. conjugate)? (This is Sylow's second theorem, but I'm seeking a more direct proof in this particular case. In fact, I also want to know if we can use this case to prove Sylow's second theorem by imbedding any group into $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$?)

Comment: You could regard $P$ as the stabilizer in ${\rm GL}_n(q)$ of a maximal chain of subspaces of ${\mathbb F}_q^n$, and show that any Sylow $p$-subgroup (in fact any $p$-subgroup) stabilizes such a chain. Serre had a proof of the existence of Sylow $p$-subgroups of finite groups that involved embedding into a linear group, but I am not sure about the conjugacy part.

Comment: @Derek Holt: I think the stablizer (the subgroup of all upper triangular matrices)is bigger than $P$? How to see any Sylow $p$-subgroup stablizes some maximal filtration directly?

Comment: Yes, by the stabilizer, I really meant the subgroup that fixes each subspace in the chain and induces the trivial representation on each quotient in the chain. That subgroup really is $P$. The fact that it stabilizes a maximal filtration (in that sense) follows from the fact that the only irreducible representation of a finite $p$-group in characteristic $p$ is the trivial one of dimension $1$. For finite fields you can prove that by a simple counting argument (it's essentially the same as the proof that $p$-groups have nontrivial centres).

Comment: “ The fact that it stabilizes a maximal filtration (in that sense) follows from the fact that the only irreducible representation of a finite p-group in characteristic p is the trivial one of dimension 1.” Is this invoking Jordan-Holder’s theorem?

Comment: Not really. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572564)

Comment: I mean why all irreducible representations trivial implies the existence of a such maximal filtration?

Comment: That's a straightforward induction on $n$.